# Not sure how to create FK relationship using Code First Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following entities:

```
  public class Bicycle
       {
           public int BicycleId { get; set; }
           public DateTime YearOfManufacture { get; set; }
           public BicycleType BicycleType { get; set; }
       }

   public class BicycleType
       {
            public int BicycleTypeId { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }
```

Every Bicycle must have just one BicycleType. A BicycleType could be associated with none to many Bicycles. I'm not sure how to create a Fluent Api FK relationship in this situation between Bicycle and BicycleType.

Comment: You must have tried something...

Answer (score 1):

Start here.   This site has a lot of good info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620